# Using the Ruby to Java Bridge (RJB) how can I access Scala classes with generic signatures?

Tags: java, ruby, scala, rjb

As an example, trying to access the Scala/Java API for Kafka from Ruby, (after the require and Rjb::load steps)

```
ProducerData = Rjb::import('kafka.javaapi.producer.ProducerData')
topic = "test"
msg = "message"
producer_data = ProducerData.new_with_sig('Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;',topic,msg)
```

In the Kafka API, the ProducerData method is defined as:

```
class ProducerData[K, V](private val topic: String,
                     private val key: K,
                     private val data: java.util.List[V])
```

The result after running the file is:

```
./test-rjb.rb:30:in `new_with_sig': Constructor not found (RuntimeError)
```

How can I properly access classes with generic type signatures?

Comment: I don't know Ruby/RJB but my guess is that your constructor takes 3 parameters and you specified only 2 in the signature. As for generics, I suggest you to try this signature: `Ljava.langString;Ljava.lang.Object;Ljava.util.List;`

Comment: Good observation @ghik. This works.